# Reset the value of a label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, label

I have the following label, where inside the label is a div that holds the text. I would want that when the user hits the button delete as shown in the picture, 
[image]

the text gets rephrase to what is shown on the second picture.

[image]

Below is the code of the label:

```
<label id="uploadedInfo"><div id="result">Item to be uploaded</div></label> <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteUpload"> Delete </button>
```

Where the text display in the div is derived from the URL generated by the Google Drive Picker.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1 What have you tried so far (jquery) and 2 why are you putting a div inside a label?

Comment: Thanks for your response, the reason I have a div inside the label its because that's where the text (URL) is generated. This is also why an id, as it makes reference to a javascript function that generates the link (text) into the div

Comment: Why cant you generate the text inside the Label? Its bad practice to have a div inside a label. Only text should be inside a label. So instead of referencing the div just reference the label and append your text there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ditch the div inside the label. Then add the following inside the opening tag of the button:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('uploadedInfo').innerHTML = 'Item to be uploaded';"
```

Updated code:

```html
<label id="uploadedInfo">Test Data</label> <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteUpload" onclick="document.getElementById('uploadedInfo').innerHTML = 'Item to be uploaded';"> Delete </button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. The reason I had the div inside is because using the id="result' it makes reference to the javascript function that generates the text. I am trying to figure out ways to also include that in your great suggestion.

Comment: You can just change `document.getElementById('uploadedInfo').innerHTML` to `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. As you can see Im quite novice at this, so if you could slightly elaborate more that would be helpful. One minor concern is that on page load Item to be uploaded would be displayed initially, that value gets changed once the user retrieves a file from google drive, and that value gets change to its initial state once they hit delete.

Comment: getElementById enables you to address an object based on its ID parameter. You can change the actual text inside the DIV in your code an that will be the page default. The button press will replace this value.

Comment: thanks for your response. I am really a novice at this, could you elaborate a bit

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: With your help, I have resolve the issue. Below is the result <label id="result" style=">Item to be uploaded</label> <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteUpload" onclick="document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Item to be uploaded';"> Delete </button> </form>

Comment: Glad you're all sorted. :)

Answer (score 0):

So on clicking of the button you can replace the value inside the label with your desired text.

```
$("#deleteUpload").click(function(){
    $("#uploadedInfo").val("Item to be uploaded")
})
```

There is also `$("#uploadedInfo").empty()` if you just want to have it cleared.

Also I removed the div inside because it is redundant. You can call upon the label if you need to alter the text or get the text.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it makes a lot of sense, but then how I tie the id="result" into this where i included it within a div because it makes reference to the javascript function that generates the text

Comment: So anywhere you were referring the div instead reference the Label. So if you were grabbing the div like this $("#result").text() instead just grab the label like this $("#uploadedInfo").text().

Comment: I see. Thanks for all of your suggestion. One minor concern I have is that on page load Item to be uploaded would be displayed initially, that value gets changed once the user retrieves a file from google drive, and that value gets change to its initial state once they hit delete.